# Filtering Model Instances In ModelForm Field

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-queryset, modelform

I apologise if this has been covered in another question - I'm new to Django and may have been staring at this along with the many other questions on Stack a little too long now..

Using Django 1.8.2, I have a modelform which shows a list of users, for which I want to exclude the current user from (i.e. you can't see yourself). I'm attempting to do this by overriding the **init** method to exclude the current user from the "to_user" list. I am getting the below error ("Invitation has no to_user"), which I don't understand. Shouldn't the field be populated from the to_user ForeignKey field in the model?

Your help and time are very much appreciated -

Specific error is:

[image]

My **model** is:

```
class Invitation(models.Model):
    from_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="invitations_sent")
    to_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="invitations_received", verbose_name="User to Invite", help_text="This is Help Text") # Verbose name is the form label for Foreigh Key vars
    message = models.CharField("Optional Message", max_length=300, blank=True) # Can add string for lavel, Setting blank=True means the field won't be required with ModelForm
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

My **form class** is:

```
class InvitationForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta: # Class Meta sets the model class that the form needs to be auto-created for
        model = Invitation
        exclude = ['from_user']

    def __init__(self, user, **kwargs):
        super(InvitationForm, self).__init__(user, **kwargs)
        self.fields['to_user'].queryset = Invitation.objects.exclude(user=self.instance.to_user)
```

My **view** is:

```
@login_required
def new_invitation(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        invitation = Invitation(from_user=request.user)
        form = InvitationForm(data=request.POST, instance=invitation)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        return redirect('user_home')
    else:
        form = InvitationForm(user=request.user)
    return render(request, "tictactoe/new_invitation.html", {'form' : form})
```

Comment: The exception mentions that the `Invitation` object does not have a `to_user` set (the field is blank)

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear why you have changed the signature of the `__init__` method. You shouldn't pass the user to the `super()` call. Since you aren't using the `user` anywhere, and you aren't passing it when you instantiate the form, I would remove it.

Secondly, you probably want to exclude `instance.from_user` instead of `instance.to_user`.

```
class InvitationForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(InvitationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['to_user'].queryset = Invitation.objects.exclude(user=self.instance.from_user)
```

Comment: Glad you figured it out :)

Answer (score 1):

My problem was trying to build a queryset from the Invitation model which didn't contain what I was looking to filter on. Taking Alasdair's advice on-board also, the, key was to import the User model to my forms.py file, then build the queryset on the User model, passing in the logged-in user from the view.

My **ModelForm** now looks like:

```
class InvitationForm(ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = kwargs.pop('user')
        super(InvitationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['to_user'].queryset = User.objects.exclude(id=user.id)

    class Meta:
        model = Invitation
        exclude = ['from_user']
```

Instantiated from the **View**:

```
@login_required
def new_invitation(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        invitation = Invitation(from_user=request.user)
        form = InvitationForm(user=request.user, data=request.POST, instance=invitation)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('user_home')
    else:
        form = InvitationForm(user=request.user)
    return render(request, "tictactoe/new_invitation.html", {'form' : form})
```

Thank you, everyone, for your help.